# Display data to Debug Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary, uwp

I writing app for UWP

I have this code

```
var p = await wc.GetProducts(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "orderby", "id" }, { "filter[search]", "1884" }
             });
```

I try to display data from dictionary like this.

```
Debug.WriteLine("There");

        Debug.WriteLine(p.products);
```

But it not works.

How I can display data of dictionary ?

Comment: using an old fashioned foreach loop wont do you?

Comment: I find the easiest way to log complex data to debug is to simply serialize the object to a JSON string, as it's only for debug purposes performance shouldn't be an issue in your actual app. I'll post a class and example usage that I use often for this purpose.

Comment: Thank's s much @mbrdev

Comment: Please see my answer below. p.Products will not work. You can only select p.name, P.title, p.description, or p.price. "P" is NOT a dictionary - it is a class

Answer (score 0):

```
To read a Dictionary --
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in p){
     Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
     Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
 }
 foreach(string key in p.Keys){
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    Console.WriteLine(p[key]);//value
 }
foreach(string value in p.Values){
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

But your problem is that P is a class called products:

```
Product p = new Product()
        {
            name = "test product 8",
            title = "test product 8",
            description = "test product 8",
            price = 8.0M
        };
```

You would access the properties of p like:

```
p.name;
p.title;
p.description;
p.price;

Debug.WriteLine(p.name);
Debug.WriteLine(p.title);//etc
```

Comment: 'WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.Product' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>'


have this error

Comment: Have to see what getProducts is and make sure that "p" is a Dictionary (just hover over it and it will let you know what type it is

Comment: You are sending a Dictionary to GetProducts - are you sure GetProducts is returning a Dictionary? One of the problems with using VAR is that you need to make sure you know what type it is representing

Comment: I hover over p. And have (local variable) ProductList p.  I using this plugin https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET

Comment: Based on that error - I'm pretty certain that GetProducts returns something other than a Dictionary.

Comment: p is a class called Products.

Comment: Yes. But p.name is product fields. I try to found order by id.

I have code for GetProducts() method, but I don't understand where I need to paste id of an order.

Answer (score 0):

Which type does `GetProducts()` return?

If it's just a `Dictionary` you can do the following:

```
foreach(var key in p.Keys)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Comment: public async Task<ProductList> GetProducts(Dictionary<string,string> parms = null)
        {
            string json = await API.SendHttpClientRequest("products", RequestMethod.GET, string.Empty, parms);
            return API.DeserializeJSon<ProductList>(json);
        }



I found this in code of plugin

Answer (score 0):

Using the below extension class (Requires Newtonsoft JSON library) you can get a JSON string of any object either with or without readable formatting.

Using the class to get a readable JSON string;

```
var p = await wc.GetProducts(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "orderby", "id" }, { "filter[search]", "1884" }
    });

var jsonString = p.ToFormattedJsonString();

Debug.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

Using the class to get a plain JSON string without format;

```
var p = await wc.GetProducts(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "orderby", "id" }, { "filter[search]", "1884" }
    });

var jsonString = p.ToJsonString();

Debug.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

You can also simplfy the above by adding your own extension method such as the below;

```
public static void ToDebug(this object data)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(data.ToFormattedJsonString());
}
```

The extension class;

```
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace System
{
    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static string ToFormattedJsonString(this object obj, bool indentWithTab)
        {
            return indentWithTab
                ? ToFormattedJsonString(obj, "\t")
                : ToFormattedJsonString(obj);
        }

        public static string ToFormattedJsonString(this object obj, string indentString = "  ")
        {
            return FormatJson(obj.ToJsonString(), indentString);
        }

        public static string ToJsonString(this object obj)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }

        public static T DeserializeJsonString<T>(this string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
        }

        private static string FormatJson(string jsonString, string indentString)
        {
            var indent = 0;
            var quoted = false;
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonString.Length; i++)
            {
                var character = jsonString[i];
                switch (character)
                {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        if (!quoted)
                        {
                            builder.AppendLine();
                            builder.RepeatAppend(++indent, indentString);
                        }
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        if (!quoted)
                        {
                            builder.AppendLine();
                            builder.RepeatAppend(--indent, indentString);
                        }
                        builder.Append(character);
                        break;
                    case '"':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        bool escaped = false;
                        var index = i;
                        while (index > 0 && jsonString[--index] == '\\')
                            escaped = !escaped;
                        if (!escaped)
                            quoted = !quoted;
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        if (!quoted)
                        {
                            builder.AppendLine();
                            builder.RepeatAppend(indent, indentString);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        if (!quoted)
                            builder.Append(" ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        builder.Append(character);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public static StringBuilder RepeatAppend(this StringBuilder builder, int count, string format,
            params object[] parameters)
        {
            if (count <= 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
                return builder;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat(format, parameters);
            }

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'StringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'RepeatAppend' and no extension method 'RepeatAppend' accepting a first argument of type 'StringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Milano C:\Users\nemes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\JsonExtensions.cs 50 Active

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot that this extension class uses another extension class! I will update to keep it all in the single class for you.